# Что такое нативные запросы SQL?

Tags: java, sql, h2

Как понять, что такое нативный SQL запрос (гуглил, но толком не понял)?

Возможно ли использовать нативный запрос с базой H2?

Comment: нативный, когда пишешь сам полностью запрос типа `SELECT id, name, last_name FROM users WHERE id IN (1,2,3)`

Comment: понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Нативный" - значит родной для определенной БД или фреймворка.

Т.е. `native H2 SQL` - это SQL, родной для `H2`.

В [документации](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_hibernate) сказано, что вы можете использовать либо Hibernate диалект либо `native H2` диалект, т.е. родной для `H2`:

> This database supports Hibernate version 3.1 and newer. You can use
> the HSQLDB Dialect, or the native H2 Dialect.
>
> When using Hibernate, try to use the H2Dialect if possible. When using
> the H2Dialect, compatibility modes such as MODE=MySQL are not
> supported. When using such a compatibility mode, use the Hibernate
> dialect for the corresponding database instead of the H2Dialect; but
> please note H2 does not support all features of all databases.

Comment: спасибо! теперь прояснилось